# How to return the outputs of mexFunction() in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mex

I have this code in C:

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//...

 int callFun(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int aa = 4;
     printf ( "\naa value = %d\n",aa);
 return aa;
 }

//...
```

and I want to call it using Matlab. To do this, I have created this ***mexFunction()***

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
    {
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv;
    int i, result;

    argc = nrhs;
    argv = (char **) mxCalloc( argc, sizeof(char *) );

    for (i = 0; i < nrhs; i++){
        if( !mxIsChar( prhs[i] ) ){
        mexErrMsgTxt("Input must be of type char.");
        return;
        }
        argv[i] = mxArrayToString( prhs[i] );
    }

    result = callFun( argc, argv );

    for( i=argc-1; i>=0; i-- )
        mxFree( argv[i] );

    mxFree( argv );
    if( result )
        mexErrMsgTxt("main function causes an error");
}
```

However, I do not know how to get ***aa*** value, when I call callFun() in Matlab.

```
>> Outputs = callFun('callFun','ff');  % this should returns aa value
```

**Is it possible to improve mexFunction for better performance?**

Comment: Regarding your second question about performance: the answer is “maybe”. Make sure you compile using optimization. Your code maybe could be rewritten to be more efficient. And you could avoid the conversion of your numeric arguments to strings and back by not calling the internal function using just strings as input. But all of this depends on what that code actually is. This should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mxCreateDoubleScalar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublescalar.html):

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar((double)result);
```

I suggest you cast the value to `double`, as that is MATLAB’s native type. You can pass the `int` as `int32` to MATLAB, but that is more involved and not as convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I want to return an array of more than one values (with different types), instead of a value?

Comment: @SHdotCom: Then you create a suitable output array with `mxCreateDoubleMatrix`, get its data pointer with `mxGetPr`, and write your values into it.

Comment: You don't need the (double) cast with the mxCreateDoubleScalar( ) call since you get that as an automatic type promotion from the compiler.

Comment: @James: Indeed. I wanted to make the cast explicit for clarity.